# drupal 6: passing multiple arguments to a view using code

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a template file that uses execute_display to pass arguments to a view and this works great for single arguments. However, one of my arguments is a taxonomy id and the form allows the user to choose multiple term ids.

I've set the view to accept multiple arguments in the form 1+2+3 etc. But when i pass execute_display an array array containing arguments in the form of term1+term2 it doesn't work.

Any ideas how to pass multiple ids as one argument using code

Comment: Kind of difficult to give you a straight answer based on the info you provided... Can you post some sample code along with what happens when the code is executed? Or maybe even a little more in-depth explanation of what your situation is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the array must be array in "execute" then this array in array - in "preview", e.g

```
$args = array($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
$view2->execute('block_1', $args);
print  $view2->preview('block_1', array($args));
```